# Cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import pyautogui
import time
from PIL import _imaging
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

time.sleep(5)
captura = pyautogui.screenshot()
codigo = captura.crop((872, 292, 983, 337))
codigo.save(r'C:\autobot_wwe_supercard\imagenes\codigo.png')
time.sleep(2)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program     
Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(r'D:\codigo.png'))
```

And this error pops up: ImportError: cannot import name '*imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL_*init**.py)

I installed pillow in console with pip install pillow

I installed pytesseract in console with pip install pytesseract

Comment: Why are you doing `from PIL import _imaging`?  If such an object even exists, it's an internal detail of PIL that you shouldn't need to use.  For that matter, why are you importing PIL at all?  You aren't directly using it (and any indirect use by the other modules you import does not require *you* to import it).

Comment: the thing is that when I import pytesseract it gives me two errors, but when I import them it only gives me one and is that.

Comment: You should show *those* errors, then.

Comment: my bad, I'm new at this so I don't really get how it works. Do I edit this post with whats happening now or do I create a new one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Python import Image from PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears as if a lot of PIL ImportErrors can simply be fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling Pillow again according to this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil/31728305) and your specific problem can be found [here](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/171).

Try these three commands:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: thanks, that error disapeared but now i got the "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application" when it imports pytesseract.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337501/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-nltk) help?

Comment: i think i have to change the python program to 32bit, but I cant find where to download a recent version in 32bit

Comment: `python3.9 -m pip install --user --upgrade Pillow` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I needed *Pillow* in *PyCharm* with Python3.9.
Pillow was installed in Python3.8. Perhaps as user. PyCharm could find it with Py3.8, but not with Py3.9

This solved it for me:

```
sudo python3.9 -m pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

Upgrade it as sudo with that python version, which the script shall run with. Maybe, *sudo* is not needed, if you want to run it only in a virtual environment or as actual user.

Comment: Worked for me running anaconda/Jupyter from VS Code on Ubuntu 22.04 where the same error was prompted when importing matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

PIL has some binary dependencies which are tied to the version of Python they were built against.

In my case, the solution was to edit the runtime settings of my Amazon Lambda function and change it to an older version of Python which matched my dev environment.

The same error will occur if pillow was installed for an incompatible CPU architecture.