# Why PIL is not working on miniconda python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, importerror, miniconda

```
from PIL import image
ImportError: cannot import name 'image' from 'PIL' (<path>9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

pip install, conda install all tested.

May anyone experienced same thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Python import Image from PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505958/why-cant-python-import-image-from-pil)

Comment: also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998199/cannot-import-name-imaging-from-pil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just update the packages and resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
from PIL import Image
```

for additional help please refer this - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html