# python having issue to load dll

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I have confirmed: MSFTFTCJTAG.dll exists in C:\ddey_documents. Having issue in loading it. Any help?

```
import os
from ctypes import *
os.chdir(r'c:\ddey_documents')
Flywatter2 = WinDLL(r"C:\ddey_documents\MSFTFTCJTAG.dll")
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\ddey_documents\MSFTFTCJTAG.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Things I have tried:

1. tried adding following without help:
   `os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\ddey_documents)`
2. Was getting following error initially, `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` It got fixed by applying following two steps:

   - swtiching to Python 32 bit version. [OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application - nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337501/oserror-winerror-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-nltk)
   - Installing plugins: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304716/5769463 to see dependencies of your dll and ensure they can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I have now able to use dumpbin to check all dependencies for the DLL:

1. install Visual Studio (I did Community version)
2. open --> Tools --> Command Line --> Developers Command Prompt
3. Type `dumpbin`
4. If it says `can't find dumpbin`. You need to go to --> folder where Visual Studio installed --> 2019 --> `Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\Hostx64\x64` and install `editbin.exe`
5. Run your dll: `dumpbin /DEPENDENTS MSFTFTCJTAG.dll`

Results:

[image]